# Spark SQL get max & min dynamically from datasource

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using Spark SQL where I want to fetch whole data everyday from a Oracle table(consist of more than 1800k records). The application is hanging up when I read from Oracle hence I used concept of **partitionColumn,lowerBound & upperBound**. But,the problem is how can I get l**owerBound & upperBound value of primary key column dynamically**?? Every day value of lowerBound & upperBound will be changing.Hence how can I get the boundary values of primary key column dynamically?? Can anyone guide me an sample example for my problem?

Comment: You do not necessarily need this. the lower bound and upper bound are used to partition between executors (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases). This means that even if they are wrong, nothing really happens except some skew between the executors. Unless the changes are really big causing big skew in certain cases you can probably get away with giving approximate values. BTW even if there are values outside of the limit, they will still go to some executor (i.e. don't worry about outliers)

Answer (score 5):

Just fetch required values from the database:

```py
url = ...
properties = ...
partition_column = ...
table = ...

# Push aggregation to the database
query = "(SELECT min({0}), max({0}) FROM {1}) AS tmp".format(
    partition_column, table
)

(lower_bound, upper_bound) = (spark.read
    .jdbc(url=url, table=query. properties=properties)
    .first())
```

and pass to the main query:

```py
num_partitions = ...

spark.read.jdbc(
    url, table, 
    column=partition_column, 
    # Make upper bound inclusive 
    lowerBound=lower_bound, upperBound=upper_bound + 1, 
    numPartitions=num_partitions, properties=properties
)
```